# What's the default value for the second parameter of eth_getBalance() if not supplied

Tags: json-rpc, balances, documentation

It's not clear in the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance), but this function works if the 2nd parameter is not passed. What's the default if not passed?

Answer (score 1):

At least for the EthereumJ (i.e. Java) implementation there are 2 versions of the function: one that takes the two arguments mentioned in the documentation, and one that takes only the first of the two arguments (i.e. the address string).

If you pass just the address string, the single-argument version is invoked.

The Java implementation is below. It shows the second argument is defaulted to "latest".

See [`JsonRpcImpl.java`](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/898a2867671c718064969f659f89478d87f1f44f/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/jsonrpc/JsonRpcImpl.java) for the code.

```
   public String eth_getBalance(String address) throws Exception {
        String s = null;
        try {
            return s = eth_getBalance(address, "latest");
        } finally {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("eth_getBalance(" + address + "): " + s);
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** See [Eth's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4356/52) for advice on other clients.

Answer (score 1):

### Behavior that might not be supported across clients

The default is to use the `latest` block, which means that `eth_getBalance` will return the balance of the account according to the most recently mined block that the client/node has.  The `latest` block is equivalent to `eth_blocknumber`.

### Behavior according to JSON-RPC spec

You are correct that per the **[JSON-RPC spec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance), the second parameter is required.**  Technically all clients should implement the spec, but some clients are not 100% compliant to the spec (and bugs should be filed).  **When using `eth_getBalance` it is advisable to call it according to the JSON-RPC spec, since there are no guarantees about all clients being able to handle the single parameter.**  The single parameter request may work with EthereumJ, but might not work Geth or cpp-ethereum.

Contrast this with [`web3.eth.getBalance`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetbalance), where the second parameter is indeed optional.